# Automake - problem with installing version automake-1.14.1

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, automake

I have problem with installing automake 1.14.1 on Rapbian (2014-09-09-wheezy-raspbian) distro. I wrote `sh ./configure` and then I wrote `make` then terminal wrote me that:

```
$ make    
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && "/home/pi/LIBRARY/automake-1.14./twrap/aclocal-1.14"
Can't locate /home/pi/LIBRARY/automake-1.14.1/bin/aclocal in @INC (@INC contains:
/etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5usr
/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at 
/home/piLIBRARY/automake-1.14.1/t/wrap/aclocal-1.14 line 29.Makefile:2493: recipe 
for target 'aclocal.m4' failed make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 2
```

I don't know what does it mean. Can you help me what to do next?

Comment: There should be a script called `autogen` or `autogen.sh`. Try running that first.

Comment: All it often would contain is `autoreconf -fi`, which is why autogen.sh generally does not exist in many projects.

Comment: I don't have neither autogen.sh script nor autoreconf in the automake install folder. When I tried  write an autogen or autoreconf -fi so error message is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what is problem in. I use `filezilla` to transport `automake` to Raspberry Pi (running on Raspbian) in unpacked form. When I transported packed `automake.tar` through fillezila and then unpacked it on RPi and did installation of this one then I have no problem. However many thanks for all your answers and an effort to help me.

Answer (score 0):

after this `aclocal` error I typed `autogen.sh` and it gave me

```
**Error**: You must have `libtool' installed.
You can get it from: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/
```

error. I installed `libtool` and typed

```
autogen.sh
make
```

and `make` worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reason I found here. First as already mentioned by @peter for filezilla. Other reason is putting the file in some folder. I tried to install both wiringPi and bcm2835-xx from Document folder and aclocal.m4 error was happening.

When I put tar file on home/pi directory and followed the process, it worked.